# accidentally sent slp to slp contract address

Tags: erc-20

please help. I accidentally sent smooth love potion to slp contract address ronin:cc8fa225d80b9c7d42f96e9570156c65d6caaa25. Is there any way I can get them back? tried the sky mavis support but they haven't responded for a really long while.